# When Entity Framework 7.0 will be released?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to know the exact date the Entity Framework 7.0 will be released?
Also, Will be a performance difference between EF6.0 and EF 7.0

Comment: check this https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: I believe you're asking the wrong place.

Comment: Hi all, I already checked the link but nothing tell us the exact release date of EF 7.0 or EF Core 1.0

Comment: When it's done - and not a day earlier ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 1.0 and EF Core 1.0 will be released end of June 2016, accroding to this blog post on the .NET blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/

And yes, there will be a performance difference, as EF Core is esentially a brand new product, that shares name (and some APIs) with Entity Framework 6.x and earlier.

You can see some performance demos here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B852

Comment: It doesn't really share the API with EF6. There are plenty of similarities, sure, but also a huge amount of differences. And even when there are types that are mostly the same between EF6 and EF7, they're not in the same namespace. (Also, what's "this" blog post? Are you missing a link?)

Comment: Added missing blog post link...

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, are you sure? as the link doesn't mention anything related to EF Core, it mentions only ASP.NET Core and .NET Core and I think EF Core is other team

Comment: Yes, I am sure! EF Core 1.0 comes with ASP.NET Core / .NET Core

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/ef/core/what-is-new/#release-planning-and-schedules